# Deja-dup has an error backing up after updating to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: snap, deja-dup

I updated to 20.04 a couple days ago and now deja-dup won't backup.  I'm backing up to a network server and the error is

```
BackendException: Could not initialize backend: /snap/core18/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1: undefined symbol: __clock_nanosleep, version GLIBC_PRIVATE
```

Comment: I created a bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/deja-dup/+bug/1875215
So, please join for that bug report as I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved installing Déjà Dup from flathub

https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.DejaDup